# How to Avoid token deletion in a NSTokenField

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Is it possible to avoid token deletion (pressing delete key after selecting a token) in NSTokenField ?
If so can you please help me with a sample code.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Implement `- (BOOL)control:(NSControl *)control textView:(NSTextView *)textView doCommandBySelector:(SEL)commandSelector;` and check if the commandSelector is equal to `- (void)deleteBackward;`. Also check if the current selection represents a token. If both is true, return `NO`.